# MongoDB field returns a number but makes javascript variable undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

The value of

> found.totalfunds = 99

But when im assigning it to variable

> funds

it returns undefined on console.log(funds)

```
 router.get("/:id/managefunds/",middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){

    console.log("Manage Funds");
     var societyId = req.params.id;
     // res.send(societyId);
     var funds ;
     Society.findById({_id:societyId},function(err,found){
        console.log("fromMongo"+found.totalFunds);
        funds = found.TotalFunds;
     });
     console.log("FUNDSSSS: "  + funds);

     res.render("campgrounds/managefunds",{parm:societyId,funds});

});
```

console.log("fromMongo"+found.totalFunds);
This returns a number I made as default.

Comment: when you print funds it's still undefined. print it inside the callback function.

Comment: I want to assign it in the query then do calculations outside.

Comment: i think just a typo  funds = found.TotalFunds, shouldn't be found.totalFunds

Comment: in my model it is totalFunds

Comment: @KrishnaSingh I found that too but it still outputs undefined in the case of funds but "369" (correctoutput) on found.totalFunds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Society.findById** has a callback because it's *asynchronous*.

You have to modify your code to continue only when the callback gets executed:

```
router.get("/:id/managefunds/",middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){

    console.log("Manage Funds");
     var societyId = req.params.id;
     // res.send(societyId);
     var funds ;
     Society.findById({_id:societyId},function(err,found){
        console.log("fromMongo"+found.totalFunds);

        funds = found.TotalFunds;     console.log("FUNDSSSS: "  + funds);

        res.render("campgrounds/managefunds",{parm:societyId,funds});
     });
});
```